# Word meaning for phenomenon where one issue is incorrectly believed to be tied to another

Tags: meaning, technology

I work in IT and we run into a common issue where whenever we announce that we have done something like adding a new feature to a program, updating servers or what have you... users start coming forward with lists of problems they have that they think are related to the changes.

For example we announced this morning that last night we turned on a feature to automate a process of sending out several different email notices to customers. This afternoon I got called into an emergency meeting about the new email "thing" being "all messed up". It turns out one user on the billing team received a standard email send reject notice from a customers email server because their mailbox was full and not accepting emails. Obviously in no way related to what we did but they had a panic attack and thought it was.

So long winded description but what i'm looking for is if there is some word or phrase for this phenomenon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are guilty of a [post hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) fallacy.

Comment: Perfect choice, and good attribution.

Comment: @JeffSahol Thanks that seems to describe the issue pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

They are assuming that *correlation* implies *causation*, when really the two are *independent* events.

Comment: ...which was ruled off-topic and closed on [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55636/correlation-vs-causation)

Comment: came here to say this

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [misattribution](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misattribute).

Comment: I agree *misattribution* can be used for errors resulting from conflation of correlation and causation, and in context there should be no ambiguity, but imho its primary context is the erroneous attribution of *words* to someone who didn't actually say/write them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [**spurious**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spurious).

In scientific / technical contexts, it means [falsely inferred causation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship).